# How to see create-react-app build logs (verbose)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

As part of create-react-build, I don't see any logs; it's a successful build as below, but I'd like to see build logs, outputs of what it build, packages compiled, if possible even some metrics (like perf, as build takes some time, profiling data as cpu, memory). I see that webpack provides some of these but nothing is visible through create react app..

Please help with how to enable those logs.

```
Compiled successfully!
This is what I see from CRA build output:

  Local:            http://localhost:3070
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.106:3070

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope, I did not figure it out